# DUDA RESUELTA: Intento realizar un UPDATE a una tabla de una base de datos, pero me salta un error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConn

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, windows-forms

Tengo como referencia esta función, en la cual una vez el usuario este accesando, el estado de **sesionActiva** se haga true:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PrototipoBeta5;Integrated Security=True");

//Guarda la sesion del alumno de entrada ingresado ya reconocida la matricula ingresada...
private void guardarRegistroEntrada(string idAlumno)
{
    //Cambia el estado de sesion a activo el alumno ingresado...
    string commanduserin = "UPDATE alumnos SET sesionActiva = @sesionActiva WHERE idAlumno = @idAlumno";

    conn.Open();
    var cmdupdatein = new SqlCommand(commanduserin, conn);

    //Parametros a comparar y a actualizar**
    cmdupdatein.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sesionActiva", true);

    cmdupdatein.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Mas que me salta este error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@idAlumno"'.
```

La estructura de la base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunos ejemplos de informacion estan por aqui...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es una vez ingresada la matricula al programa, el mismo programa la lee y obtiene el "idAlumno", para posteriormente realizar un UPDATE en la BD tabla "alumnos", simplemente en el atributo de "sesionActiva" cambie a true. Ya intente de varias maneras pero aun me marca ese error. Cabe recalcar que sin el "Where" la sentencia funciona pero cambia la "sesionActiva" a todas las filas existentes.

Comment: El error es simple, en tu `UPDATE` pasas dos parámetros `@sesionActiva` e `@idAlumno` yo no veo en ningún lado que le asignes un valor a `@idAlumno`. Y por cierto, el código va en formato texto. Otro aspecto a tener en cuenta es que deberías respetar el tipo de dato a enviar/recibir. Si en tu BD el idAlumno es INT, ¿Por qué en `C#` pones `string` idAlumno?

Comment: Hmmmm, entonces sí quiero hacer una comparacion de "idAlumno" que está dentro de la tabla "alumnos" con la variable de tipo string que recibe la funcion que tambien se llama "idAlumno" dentro de ese connectionString como sería?? Sobre lo de string idAlumno, hice conversiones previas y tambien no me jalaba... El mismo error...

Comment: El @idAlumno hago referencia a la variable externa de "idAlumno" que se recibe en la funcion guardarRegistroEntrada

Comment: Aunque tendre que hacer la conversion a int previa

Comment: El Where como quedaria al final de cuentas??

Comment: El idAlumno que esta justo despues del WHERE, hago referencia al "idAlumno" de la Base de datos de "alumnos"

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, voy aprendiendo poco a poco

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es crear otro cmdUpdate solo que este reciba el valor del idUsuario, algo así: `cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAlumno", Convert.ToInt32(idUsuario));`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Franqo :)

Comment: Agreguen la solución como respuesta con una explicación adecuada y marquen la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

El error es simple, en tu UPDATE pasas dos parámetros **@sesionActiva** e **@idAlumno** yo no veo en ningún lado que le asignes un valor a **@idAlumno**. Otro aspecto a tener en cuenta es que deberías respetar el tipo de dato a enviar/recibir.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es crear otro cmdUpdate solo que este reciba el valor del idUsuario, algo así:

```
cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAlumno", Convert.ToInt32(idUsuario));
```